# Emacs regexp-replace seems to work unexpectedly

Tags: regex, emacs, wildcard

I am trying to remove some `<span style="something not constant">` from a text and I tried `M-x replace-regexp> "<span*>" -> ""`

but it does nothing.  I made sure the cursor is at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must probably know that * in a regex means 'repetition', and i'm not sure you want to remove something like `<spannnnn>`, do you ?

What you mean is probably: `<span.*>`

PS: Made the same mistake as you ;)

Comment: oh im terribly sorry, fixed it

Comment: Thanx that worked!! but it still doesnt find the first ">", it rather finds tha one at the end of line... eg: `<span syle="jhdkljhf"><p><\p>` i removes thw whole line

Comment: That's because the regex is greedy, you might want to use .*?

Comment: A nicer way would be `<span[^>]*>`